# Why is `func` not a function here in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am learning `mongodb`, and in the book, there's a code

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testdb";
module.exports = function (func) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
      console.log("connected");
      func(db);
      db.close();
    }
  });
};
```

I run this code, but throw the error `TypeError: func is not a function`, I googled, but lots of codes like this, my mongodb version is 4.0, and node.js  version is 9.10, any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the consumer isn't calling it with a function.

Comment: ie. `module.exports("not a function")` could cause that error.

Comment: @user2864740 it shows `TypeError: module.exports is not a function`.

Comment: After the assignment to `module.exports`, where such is in scope.. however, since it's an *export* ta-da, it's whatever "consumes" the module which should be focused on. Here is small repro of what the issue 'is', everything else aside: `(function (f) { return f() })("need to pass a function")`. This error is only throwable if 'whatever' called the 'exports' function supplied a non-Function parameter.

Comment: @user2864740 I find that, thank you, I think the code in book is right, but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever `func` you are passing must be a function.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testdb";
module.exports = function (func) { //func must be function, dont pass just a variable
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
      console.log("connected");
      func(db);
      db.close();
    }
  });
};
```